# Problems sign up to facebook with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rubygems

when I sign up using facebook my url is http://localhost:3000/registration then it will change to [http://localhost:3000/registration#*=*](http://localhost:3000/registration#_=_) but it wont let me login that the only thing it changes on that page just the url.

[image: command line]

#### Contoller

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
  # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user,
         :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") \
        if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

#### User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
         :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable
  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}

  def self.from_omniauth(auth) 
    user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first

    if user
      return user
    else
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.fullname = auth.info.name  
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.provider = auth.provider
        # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
        # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
        user.skip_confirmation!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Now, when I formatted the code so that it is at least readable, please let us know: _what is your question?_

Comment: Also, please put a plain text instead of the image; the latter is not readable at all.

Comment: It is going into the `else` part in `OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook` action. Before redirecting in else part, do `raise @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')`

Comment: There is a `rollback transaction` in your server log. It means there is something went wrong in the `else` part of `User.from_omniauth`. That is why you cannot sign in.

Comment: Email can't be blank I got this error @JagdeepSingh                                                
    after I inserted this  raise @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have validation for `:fullname` and ofcourse when you try to create user you receive validation error and rollback.

Try `first_or_initialize` instead `first_or_create` and don't forget `save!` user.

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.fullname = auth.info.name  
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.provider = auth.provider
        # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
        # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.save!
      end
```

P.S
`where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)` this line is suspicious. I don't understand how user will be finded by uid and provider and if that will be finded, why you change his attributes?
For exemple, you have one user, and this user not finded by email but finded by uid and provider. You change his email, password, and after that user can't authorize by email.

Maybe you have to create new model `authorization` wich will belongs to user and find user by authorization. In this case you can add more providers for user.

```
class Authorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
           :rememberable, :trackable, 
           :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable
    validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
    has_many :authorizations

    def self.from_omniauth(auth) 
      authorization = Authorization.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).last
      return authorization.user if authorization

      user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: auth.info.email)
      if user.persisted?
        user.authorizations.create(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)            
      elsif user.new_record?
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.fullname = auth.info.name  
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.save!
        user.authorizations.create(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)          
      end   
      return user
    end
  end
```

Comment: @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ') this code give a reason why I couldn't do it cause i had invalid email thank you

Comment: Yep. Of course. How I forget that. Email and password is required for user by devise.